# Does it make sense to use key-mirror in react native project?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, google-closure-compiler

[Key mirror](https://github.com/STRML/keyMirror) is a simple package which is used to create an object with values equal to its key names. It is first used in facebook react project.

From a [comment](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/1639#issuecomment-45188026) here, it seems to me that this package only makes sense when being applied to react web project, as it can survive google closure advanced mode to make web load faster.  I am wondering if anyone use it in a react native project, as I tend to think there's no point using it in app development.

thanks :)